# Android - Retrieve a thumbnail of a video from the server and display on phone

Tags: android, video-streaming, thumbnails

My question is how do I retrieve a thumbnail of a video(for example, video present at http://www.yo-yo.org/mp4/yu.mp4). I want to first download just a thumbnail from the server and display it on the phone and when the user clicks on the thumbnail, will start the video player using the uri of the video file.

So, what is the process to create a thumbnail directly from the server, as I see some methods for files which are actually present in the sdcard(but I am not looking for these styles).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Assuming a web-site application

U can simply read the first video Key-Frame / I-Frame and have it decoded using eg. ffmpeg, however, for that you'll to implement C++ code, probably in your backend to read that first frame and convert it to, eg. a JPEG, and then, send it back to the caller ( web-page )